# How to set the absolute top style with jquery?

Tags: jquery

After searching, I'm trying this code which I'm pretty sure was suppose to work:

```
$("#someLinkID").click(
    function () {
        var divToRender = "<div>" + "some message" + "</div>";
        $(divToRender).css({ top: 0, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
        $(this).append(divToRender);
    }
);
```

What am I missing, that looks very logical...

Comment: You should not be inserting divs into links. Perhaps you mean $('body').append(divToRender)?

Comment: I am wrapping the ready function, the fiddler example you sent doesn't work, if you change the top from 0 you can see it stays the same

Comment: I want to manipulate the div to display right below the div (top and left) that's why I'm doing it

Comment: Try setting the CSS after you've added the div: http://jsfiddle.net/e5zJ2/4/

Comment: @Vlad: that's what I considered originally, too, but using `css()` to change the `color` (before appending to the document) [works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e5zJ2/6/), oddly. And more oddly seems to work while setting the position [before appending](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e5zJ2/7/), now. Mind, in both those demos (and your own) `divToRender` is created as a jQuery object, rather than a jQuery-wrapped HTML-string. Which I suspect is the crux.

Comment: @DavidThomas, that is indeed very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally saw the mistake (that the CSS wasn't being applied), to ensure that it *is* applied (though I can't say why it, originally, wasn't) I'd recommend:

```
$("#someLinkID").click(
    function () {
        $('<div />', {'text' : 'some message'})
        .css({top: 0, left: 0, position : 'absolute'})
        .appendTo($(this));
    }
);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e5zJ2/3/).